# ExtJS 4.2.2 theming guide mentions sencha app build, but use sencha compile ...?

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

The ExtJS 4.2.2 theming guide mentions sencha app build, but shouldn't we be using sencha compile ...?

It seems sencha app build is deprecated, but where can we find a doc with examples on how to use sencha compile with the right options and parameters.

For now, what are the equivalents for these commands:

sencha app build
sencha package build
sencha ant clean

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also I would suggest not crossposting your questions here when you have posted them in the forum. As far as I know none of the support folks monitor StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You got it wrong: `sencha app build` supersedes `sencha compile`, not the vice versa.